# Regex: Help needed to match text bits

Tags: regex, match

I need to match these texts bits, I know I must use regex but how?

- `AR19`
- `AE17`
- `BR15`
- `C214`

I know it would be this in a non regex form:

`(A/B/C)+(1/2)/(R/E)+(11-29)`

Where :

- `()` would be one character
- `/` would be `or`

I tested this but it didn't work, what am I doing wrong ?

`[A-C][A-Z]|[1-2][11-19]`

Thanks
Blaxou

Comment: You should spell out the rules for your patterns. Providing just a sample of test cases most likely means your forgetting about some case(s), and any pattern you receive here will therefore be incomplete.

Comment: [regexr](http://regexr.com/) is online tool which can help you to build and test regular expressions. it has examples and references which can help you to learn regular expressions.

Comment: Maybe [`^[ABC][12]?[RE]?(?:1[1-9]|2[0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/N5s0PH/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only watch to match those things, and you want the regex to be very similar to the example you provided, then this should work:

```
[ABC][12RE][12][1-9]
```

A working example can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/I8tAOr/5).